# How to repair/recover Snow Leopard when the installation DVD has been lost?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, dvd

So I seem to not have my Snow Leopard DVD available anywhere.

I can't use a newer version like Lion.

What can I do to repair/recover Snow Leopard now that the installation DVD is not available?

Comment: Do you live near an Apple Store? They can probably sort you out.

Comment: Have you determined what sort of repair is needed? Do you want to run Disk Utility or reinstall the software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you computer not booting is the reason you need your Snow Leopard disc, there are several things to try and troubleshoot your issue.

1. Boot into single user mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> @ POST (chime)).  Once the command prompt comes up, type `fsck -fy`.  This will attempt to repair your disk.
2. If this is okay, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> at POST and see if it boots.  This disables kexts, fonts, etc.
3. If this does not work try verbose mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> @ POST) and see where your computer stops loading at and troubleshoot from there.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

An unrepairable disk error requires an Erase/Install of OS X.  It may not cause issues right away, so get the files transferred now.
In fact it may fail to even boot up.  The previously mentioned **shift key** at boot (**Safe Mode**) worked.

I just used Disk Utility to BACK UP the entire hard drive to a properly setup USB.  That will repair the installed OS X 10.6.8.
Carbon Copy Cloner allows bulky user files to be excluded.
I made a copy of OS X 10.6.8 installation right after Software Update was finished.
Thanks to apple discussions for tip on using a copy to repair the system.